# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: wrong version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, rest-client

I am very new for openssl. When I try to connect to the page https on console, it through error:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:url => 'https://secure2.lionair.co.id/lionairibe/OnlineBooking.aspx', :ssl_version => 'SSLv3', :method => 'get')
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: wrong version number
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
from (irb):1
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /var/www/rails/PROJ/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Then I try other version ssl: 'TLSv1'. Error still happen

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:url => 'https://secure2.lionair.co.id/lionairibe/OnlineBooking.aspx', :ssl_version => 'TLSv1', :method => 'get')
```

I am using xubuntu and my openssl version:

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
built on: Thu Jun 11 15:28:12 UTC 2015
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

Comment: Please try rephrasing the question. I have no idea what your problem currently is or what are you trying to do!

Comment: sorry about that. I edited it. Need some help please

Comment: I still don't get it. First code block looks like some random stuff. Can you open new irb (or rails s, whichever you use), do an example request and copy paste **everything** into the question?

Comment: Updated . I put everything up. Thanks @MichalSzyndel :)

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. What happens if you don't specify a version? Are you sure server cert is ok?

Comment: wow. It run fine, can't believe it. I think https must be going with ssl_version?

Comment: What I would guess is you specified invalid version string and server didn't know how to respond to this.

Comment: List of openssl versions supported by your ruby can be found here this in: `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS`, for me it returns `[:TLSv1, :TLSv1_server, :TLSv1_client, :TLSv1_2, :TLSv1_2_server, :TLSv1_2_client, :TLSv1_1, :TLSv1_1_server, :TLSv1_1_client, :SSLv3, :SSLv3_server, :SSLv3_client, :SSLv23, :SSLv23_server, :SSLv23_client]`. Maybe you need to pass a symbol instead of string? Or try out the `:TSLv1_server` version?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichalSzyndel :D

Comment: did it work? Then I'm glad to add it as an answer! :)